# How to prepare a pure sample of hexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

> To prepare a pure sample of n-hexane using sodium metal as one reactant the other reactant will be:
>
> 1. n-propyl bromide
> 2. Ethyl bromide and n-butyl bromide
> 3. Methyl bromide and n-pentyl chloride

Comment: What is the question now? Is it which of these three is correct?

Comment: Well, one is clearly better than the others...

Comment: Why is everyone so hung up over the Wurtz reaction. It is never used in real chemistry

Comment: In 35 years lab time I have never seen it used or its use proposed.

Comment: Compared to the timescale on which the new knowledge slowly seeps from the labs to the classrooms, 35 years is not all that long.

Comment: The people who set these problems clearly have no experience in running real reactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wurtz reaction is not very efficient and hard to initiate. If you use a mixture of alkyl halides you will obtain a difficult to purify mixture of products including homo-coupling from both starting materials and reduction products, so the obvious way to approach this is to use a single starting material. In this example then propyl bromide is the appropriate starting material.